# Spring Security in conjuction with Spring repositories to secure and authenticate various parts of a website

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data, spring-repositories

I was looking for a concrete, serious and complete example on how to use Spring security in a Spring Boot application that uses [Spring data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) to access the database and therefore to query about registered users.

I've seen that it's easily protected a range of webpages using Spring security by overriding the `configure` method, for example with the following options:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/vendor/**", "/templates/**")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .permitAll();
```

This code protects users for example from accessing `http://localhost:3000/home/users/`, but allows then to access `http://localhost:3000/login` or simply `http://localhost:3000`.

I've been reading around about Spring security, but I can't get how can I protect the different parts of an application, for example, when a user has logged in to the website, and prohibit him from accessing from example `http://localhost:3000/home/users/another_user`, and in general to control the access of a logged user to all parts of the website.

I'm using [Spring data repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) to manipulate data of the database through the entities.

Do you know about an example that uses Spring security in conjunction with Spring repositories (and if necessary other tools) to protect (and authenticate) different parts of a website? A (video-)tutorial may also be useful.

Thanks for any help.

Note: I've looked at the sagan website's repository, but it's quite complex to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 2):

As noted above ACLs are one option however an alternative and possibly simpler solution may to be to apply security at the method level.

See section 15.3.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

So supposing you have an URL /users/123 where 123 is the current user and which delegates to a service layer method to load the user then how do I prevent the user from tampering with the URL and seeing data returned by e.g. /users/456.

One approach is to apply method level security via the @PostAuthorize annotation:

```
@PostAuthorize("hasPermission(returnObject, null)")
public User findById(Long id) {
    return repository.findOne(id);
}
```

The security checks are delegated to an implementation of org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator

An implementation could look like the below:

```
public class BasePermissionsEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object domainObject) {
        return hasPermission(authentication, domainObject, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object domainObject, Object permission) {
        boolean hasPermission = true;

        //User is my custom class representing a logged in user
        //UserEntity is my custom interface implemented by entities associated with specific user
        //If user is an Admin allow access
        //Otherwise allow access if logged in user 'owns' the DomainObject instance
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

        if(! user.isAdmin()){
            if (domainObject instanceof UserEntity) {
                User owner = ((UserEntity) domainObject).getOwner();
                hasPermission = user.equals(owner);
            }
        }

        return hasPermission;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType,
            Object permission) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Configuration of the PermissionEvaluator looks like the following in XML so you would need to convert to Java config:

```
<security:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="permissionEvaluator" />
</bean>

<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="com.mycompany.BasePermissionsEvaluator" />
```

The following outlines converting the XML config to Java config:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/#custom-method-security

So in your existing security configuration class it looks like you would add:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true) //ADD THIS
public class MySecurityConfig{

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler() {
    DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();

    //SET TO OUR CUSTOM PERMISSIONS HANDLER DETAILED ABOVE
    expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new BasePermissionsEvaluator());

    return expressionHandler;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not having given any feedback to your answer for a long time, but I found all of these concepts not trivial and odd from my perspective, probably because I'm new to these things in general, even though I had already used `passport.js` once with Node and Express. I would have a first question or doubt. Why would we apply this `PostAuthorize` thing to a repository method? Is this because in the Spring controllers we could use this specific repository method (which contains the annotation) which does some checks?

Comment: It seems that Spring security makes everything very complex just for the simple cases...From what I remember with passport.js, it was a lot easier to setup the security for the application, but I may also be wrong or, at that time, I didn't have the whole perspective of what I was doing...

Comment: I have put it on the repository because the repository is returning an instance of the domain object which is required in the evaluator. I can't very well apply the evaluation on the controller because that will be returning something else entirely. You can apply security anywhere but this specific case checks the domain object returned by a method so repository or service layer are suitable. The logged in user has requested an entity. Allow access if the logged in user either 'owns' the requested item or has admin role, otherwise refuse access.

Comment: Ok. I would have another question. So far I've not configuration file, since I'm using Spring Boot, and it does everything for you. I've never used Spring without SpringBoot (but I may want to learn it too), so I don't know where to put the configuration files, and how to call them. Official tutorials seem to use SpringBoot and are very simple, so it's difficult to understand exactly what I should do. So, where would I put those XML specifications?

Comment: You are using Java config so you'd be better converting the XML to code. This involves adding an annotation to your existing  config class and adding a method. The exact conversion is detailed here https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/#custom-method-security:

Answer (score 1):

This is called Access Control, or "Domain Object Security" in Spring Security.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#domain-acls

You've got a lot of reading to do!

You probably want to combine it with Spring Data JPA, so that SDJ only returns the records it should. An example here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/security

Basically you're going to be adding some "row owner" info to your tables, and getting SDJ and SS to work together to control access, like:

```
@Query("select o from BusinessObject o where o.owner.emailAddress like ?#{hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') ? '%' : principal.emailAddress}")
List<BusinessObject> findBusinessObjectsForCurrentUser();
```

An alternative it to use a database server that supports Row Security, like PostgreSQL, and handle your access control right in the db.