# Spring Security and Web MVC: How to save data that belong to a user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

What is the best pattern to follow when saving an object that belongs to a authenticated user using Spring Security and Web MVC?

All the tutorials that I've come across show how to authenticate a user logging in and that's as far as they go, they don't explain how to work with multiple users and their data. For example: A logged in user is saving a new blog post. Here is what the controller looks like:

```
@PostMapping("/blog/save")
public String blogSavePost(@AuthenticationPrincipal CurrentUser currentUser, BlogForm blogForm) {
    blogService.save(currentUser, blogForm);
    return "redirect:/blog";    
}
```

Should the `currentUser` be passed to the `blogService` where the service then sets it on the entity `Blog` (which is then passed to `BlogRepository` for saving)? It seems a bit tedious to have to pass this on every save or edit..

What about when editing an object - since the id of the object being saved is passed to the controller (either as a parameter of part of the form object), it's open to being changed by a user. How should the service layer verify that the data being saved belongs to the user? I figure that there is an easy way to handle this with Spring Security, I just haven't come across what it is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

Entirely up to you. I would just set the association in the Controller before passing it to the service:

**Question 2.**

You can prevent binding of certain fields by defining a binder in youir controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("userId");
}
```

You can also use method level security to prevent users from editing entities other than those that belong to them. See here for an example:

[Spring Security in conjuction with Spring repositories to secure and authenticate various parts of a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057175/spring-security-in-conjuction-with-spring-repositories-to-secure-and-authenticat/37060389#37060389)

Alternatively you could use a Web Security expression that would secure the endpoint for save/update/delete requests.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/el-access.html#el-access-web