# Spring Security custom PermissionEvaluator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm using JWT token authorization.
I'm trying to restrict access to some of REST api endpoints. I would like it to work like that: code below should be only executed when authenticated user id == id given in `@PathVariable`

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN', 'USER')")
@GetMapping(value = "orders/{id}", produces = "application/json")
public EntityModel<Order> getOrders(@PathVariable Long id) { ... )
```

These articles more or less describe what I trying to acomplish: [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057175/spring-security-in-conjuction-with-spring-repositories-to-secure-and-authenticat/37060389#37060389), [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression)

**I don't understand how second link `CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator` should look like in my case. I would be grateful if someone would give me some tips.**

**My second concern** is that all I can do later on, is to get username `authentication.getName()`, and then i have to use `UserRepository` to `findUserByUsername(String username)`. Is it normal to do it this way? That's additional database query. I wonder if it is possible to somehow add userID to token (because function that returns `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` already is getting user by username anyway).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To trigger `PermissionEvaluator` , you have to use `hasPermission()` in `@PreAuthorize`.
There are 2 versions of `hasPermission()` which are :

(1) `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('foo' ,'bar')")`  which will call

```java
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject,Object permission);

/** targetDomainObject = 'foo',  permission = 'bar' **/
```

(2)  `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('foo' ,'bar','baz')")` which will call

```java
boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission);
/** targetId = 'foo' , targetType = 'bar' , permission = 'baz' **/
```

In both cases , the `Authentication` parameter is the `Authentication` token get from the `SecurityContext`.

One thing to note is that when configuring  `@PreAuthorize("hasPermission()")`, you can use `#foo` , `@P` or `@Param` from spring data to specify which argument in the protected method will be used to invoke the `PermissionEvaluator` . See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/#access-control-using-preauthorize-and-postauthorize) for more details.

In your case , you could do something like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('#id', 'getOrder')")
public EntityModel<Order> getOrders(@PathVariable Long id) {

}
```

and the `PermissionEvaluator` looks like :

```java
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {


    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {

            MyAuthentication myAuth = (MyAuthentication) auth;
            Long targetId =  (Long) id;
            String permssionStr = (String) permission;

            if(permssionStr.equals("getOrder")){
                return myAuth.getUserId().equals(targetId);
            }else if(permssionStr.equals("xxxx"){
                //other permission checking
            }
    }
}
```

Please note that it assumes you also customize the `Authentication` token to be `MyAuthentication` which includes userID. It also answers your 2nd concern is that you can customize the authentication process to return a customzied `Authentication` token which you can set the userId into it just after loading the user record for authentication. In this way , the `userId` will be stored inside the `MyAuthentication` which you do not need to query it again in the `PermissionEvaluator`.

Alternatively , you can also consider to directly express the authorisation logic in the `@PreAuthorize` without using `hasPermission()` for such simple case:

```java
@PreAuthorize("#id == authentication.userId")
public EntityModel<Order> getOrders(@PathVariable Long id) {

}
```

Comment: Hey, could you help me with customization of Authentication token? (I made the version without it and of course is working fine). What I return is: ```UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, grantedAuths);``` Do i have to extend it? Please at least point me some example, I tried to extend User class, hoping that i will be able to access its fields later via ```authentication.getPrincipal.getEmail()``` but it semms not working.